# Running lein repl :headless in the background

Tags: bash, clojure, signals, leiningen

## Goal: Run `lein` Headless in the Background

I am trying to run a leiningen REPL headless, without devoting a terminal to it. Namely, I would like to do

```
$ lein repl :headless &
```

But after a few seconds bash reports that it has been stopped

```
$ [2]+  Stopped                 lein repl :headless
```

Running this in zsh and sh has the same results. Those shells print the signal which is received, SIGTTIN, meaning the process attempted to read from STDIN despite not being the terminal-controlling process.

The following works:

```
$ bash -c "lein repl :headless &"
$ lein repl :headless </dev/null &
```

I've taken a look at [repl :headless does not work without stdin](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/715) but I wasn't able to resolve my problem using what was there.

---

## Some other details:

Putting

```
#!/bin/bash
lein repl :headless &
```

into a script `test.bash` and running `./test.bash` also works. But changing the line to `lein repl :headless` and running `./test.bash &` does not.

Running

```
$ lein repl :headless &
$ disown %1
```

Also does not work; `ps` of the process reports that it is terminated.

I also typically run `tmux` with `reattach-to-user-namespace`, but I have tried this inside and outside of `tmux`, and in multiple terminal emulators (iTerm2 and Terminal). If it helps, [here are my `stty -a` settings](https://pastebin.com/xEDMdSms).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lein trampoline repl :headless &` will resolve this.

You can read [this](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1173) for an explanation.